# How to replace a slash in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a little problem with my code:

```
<template slot="popover">
  <img :src="'img/articles/' + item.id + '_1.jpg'">
</template>
```

Some of my item.id numbers have a slash in them. As a result, some images are not displayed. Now I would like to replace the slash with an underline or delete it, if a slash occurs in the item.id numbers. Is there a simple solution for this?

The slash should only be replaced at this point in the code and not in another place where the item.id is used.

Comment: use a function to handle this inside like: `<img :src="'img/articles/' + handleSlash(item.id) + '_1.jpg'">`

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 16.11.1

Answer (score 5):

you can use a computed property and replace slashes by dashes with `replace` and a regex:

```
<template slot="popover">
  <img :src="`img/articles/${itemId}_1.jpg`">
</template>

<script>
...
  computed: {
    itemId: function(){
        return this.item.replace(/\//g, '-');
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

here's a test fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pqfvba6n/

Comment: I use dashes in my example, but you can use any other character like underscores like this `this.item.replace(/\//g, '_')` or remove slashes like this `this.item.replace(/\//g, '')`

Comment: I use ```:src="`img/articles/${itemId}_1.jpg`"``` instead of ```:src="'img/articles/' + itemId + '_1.jpg'"``` because I found it cleaner, but you can keep your version

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
<template slot="popover">
  <img :src="'img/articles/' + item.id.replace(/\//g, '_') + '_1.jpg'">
</template>
```

Comment: if there are many slashes, it will only replace the first, that's why I use a regex with `g` flag

Comment: The question mentions "slash" not "slashes", so should be covered with `.replace("/", "_")` Although i did edit my answer to use regex, thanks